# What are the differences between Tables and Categorical Arrays, and cell and struct arrays?

Tags: matlab

In the newest version of MATLAB there are two new data types: Tables and Categorical Arrays.

Table is a new data type suitable for holding data and metadata, and can be used with mixed-type tabular data that are often stored as columns in a text file or in a spreadsheet. It consists of rows and column-oriented variables.

Categorical arrays are useful for holding categorical data - which have values from a finite list of discrete categories.

In previous versions I would have handled these use cases using cell and struct arrays. What are the differences between these and the new data types?

Comment: I am behind the times...

Comment: Not so far behind, it just came out.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't upgraded yet so I can't play around but based on [this video](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/introducing-tables-and-categorical-arrays-79924.html) and [this article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/09/10/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-in-r2013b/) I can already see some advantages. They're not necessarily adding functionality that you couldn't do before, but rather just taking the hassle out of it. Using `readtable` over `xlsread` is immediately appealing to me. Being able to access columns by name rather than just by index is great, I do it in other languages often. In a table where column order doesn't really matter (unlike a matrix) it's really convenient to be able to address a column by it's name instead of having to know the column order. Also you can merge table using the `join` function which wasn't that easy to do with cell arrays before. I see that you can name the rows too, I didn't see what advantage that gives you and I can't play around but I know in some languages (like PANDAS in Python and I think in R as well) naming rows means you can work with time series data with different series that are not completely overlapping and not have to worry about alignment. I hope this is the case in Matlab too! Categorical arrays also look like just an extra layer of convenience, kind of like an `enum`. You never actually need a `enum` but it just makes development more pleasant.

Anyway that's just my two cents, I probably won't get an opportunity to play around with them any time soon but I look forward to using them when I do need them.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the links. I was surprised to learn that the question in on hold...

Comment: Likewise - the question is what is the difference, which isn't really a matter of opinion. I'd like to have seen what others know about them who've actually used them.

Answer (score 0):

I use the table format to organize different input/output cases in my data, where the result may come from different tables. Main advantages compared to struct or cell array:

- convenient table functions such as join, innerjoin, outerjoin
- the use of fields <> more robust programming than arrays
- data format is easy to export/import (e.g. delimited .txt file) <> no fprintf()
- the data file can be opened in excel/Calc (libreoffice) <> no .mat